# Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception

My Logcat:

> 08-23 18:57:03.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.HelloApp/com.HelloApp.TestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Can anybody tell me, why I am getting this error?

```
    public class TestActivity extends Activity 
    {
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("Test App");
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initControls();
    }
    public void initControls()
    {
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);
    //Button button=new Button(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),GetParameter.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    //startActivity( new Intent(null, GetParameter.class));
    }
    });
     }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, you have a null pointer exception. Please show us the relevant code if you want us to really help.

Comment: show your code of your TestActivity class....

Comment: As mentioned, we need more code to really help diagnose the problem, but one of your variables is null. Unfortunately this is one of the most common errors and can be tricky to diagnose. Look for the error line that points to the exact line number and that should narrow it down to where you can solve your problem quickly.

Comment: Could you show us `main.xml`?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test Button" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: @Soniya have you add the activity name in the manifeast file ? I may be wrong but please check it.

Answer (score 0):

your main.xml must be as this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"/> 
    <Button android:id="@+id/close" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Test Button" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

check it